# How to authorize my SMTP ip

Tags: smtp, gmail

when I send mail to gmail through SMTP I got a erro

550 5.7.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10336

follow the link it said

> 'The IP you're using to send email is
>   not authorized...'
>
> In order to prevent spam, Gmail
>   refuses mail when the sending IP
>   address does not match the sending
>   domain. To send mail from your server
>   to Gmail, we suggest using the SMTP
>   relay provided by your ISP. Please
>   note that we are unable to whitelist
>   IP addresses or otherwise make
>   exceptions at this time.

It seams that, gmail will test my ip with MX record, (for this test, I send from localhost), but if myhost.com has 3 MX record, will google test each MX to match my ip, or is there any 
way to bind a domain to a ip, not bind an ip to a domain.

## Update

After google, I think the most import thing is set DNS PTR.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup

Answer (score 2):

This happens when your IP address is listed in the [Spamhaus PBL](http://www.spamhaus.org/pbl/). This DNSBL contains a list of known dialup/dynamic IP address ranges which should not ordinarily be sending mail via SMTP.

To fix the problem, change your mail client's outgoing mail server settings to [connect to port 587](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287) instead of port 25.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not using SSL, which is demanded by Google.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the gmail smtp server as your outgoing mail server.  Then Gmail will authorize and process your email.